# Targeting specific IE using hack or user agent

Tags: html, css, browser

Is it better to use IE hacks to target multilple IEs 
like `(*,\0/,/9)` targeting areas at once or is it better to use user agent defined on page like 
`#ie9,#ie8`?

The first hack, saves line, however may be not a good way since we try to get rid of hacks.

Which one is better?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question of "which is better", but I'd suggest conditional comments.

Comment: conditional comments have more http calls and also is harder to maintain as well, Here we are using just one file.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you use them. In the past, I've used them to set a JS variable (like `isIE = true` or `IEVersion = 8`). From there, do as you please (like maybe add a class to the body)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is better to use the "user agent" as this is done at the server level. By using this technique the server will be sending only specific resource supported by the user.

Where as the other technique loads the entire resource and then check which browser it is, and finally display the specific resource. This affects the website performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining a class/id on the html element (either using user-agent server side or even using conditional comments) which you can then use in javascript and css.  There are two reasons I prefer this to CSS hacks:

1. The javascript/CSS is easier to read and more maintainable
2. It is a single point of control.

Server-side controlls can also allow you to serve different content as @DinashGupta says.  For the sort of IE hacks the OP is talking about this is not a big consideration in my view since the differences should be small (mainly CSS) between the versions for different browsers.  However, if you are talking about phone/tablet/desktop then it becomes a much larger consideration and also supports the idea of a server-side control.  Yes, you can spoof your user-agent string (IE 11 anyone?) but if you do so you live with the consequences.